# How to enable mysqli_init, MYSQLI_ASYNC in php (LAMP server)

Tags: php, drupal, mysqli, server, lamp

I am using Drupal 7.39, I want to enable `mysqli_init`, `MYSQLI_ASYNC`, `mysqli_reap_async_query` on my server, I tried with `php.ini` file but I couldn't find anything there, can anyone guide me on this as I do not have much knowledge about the server configurations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: LAMP - which linux distribution? The generic answer would be: get the php_mysqli.so and place it where all the other extensions modules are located, check via `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` which php.ini you have to edit, make sure the line `extension=php_mysqli.so` is in that file (add it if necessary; remove any trailing ; which makes it a comment), save the .ini file, restart webserver process. mysqli_reap_async_query was introduced with php 5.3.0, but that is hopefuly not a problem and your php version is way more recent.

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK, I have installed mysqli.so through **yum install php-mysqlnd** and restarted httpd service, extensions are enabled automatically, no need to place it in php.ini.